# How convert decimal to Hexadecimal in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bashrc, hexadecimal

I am using a bash file in Ubuntu and i wrote an executable code in this file that must use some Hexadecimal number.

But I just have decimal numbers so I want to convert decimal numbers to Hexadecimal numbers automatically by some command.

This is a part of my code :

```
x=1
while [ $x -lt 255 ];do
$tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 10:0 prio 5 u32 ht 2:$x: \
match ip dst 192.168.67.$x flowid 10:$x
x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

in this section "u32 ht 2:$x:" in my code "$x" must be in Hexadecimal form and in other section must be in decimal form.but my problem is in Hexadecimal form.
How can i convert it in my code and use it ?

Comment: Your question is very vague. An example of your file would be useful.

Comment: [Convert decimal to hexadecimal in UNIX shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/379422)

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

The command to convert a  decimal number to hexadecimal is:

```
echo "obase=16; decimal-number"|bc
```

where for *decimal-number* replace a decimal number. GNU `bc` is an interactive calculator language. `obase` defines the conversion base for the output number.

Alternative command that prompts the user to type a number:

```
printf "Type a number: " && read dec && printf -v hex "%x" $dec && echo $hex
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awk [Velour library](//github.com/svnpenn/velour):

```
$ velour -n 'print n_baseconv(15, 10, 16)'
F
```

Or:

```
$ velour -n 'print n_baseconv(ARGV[1], 10, 16)' 15
F
```